# life-span and scope of oAuth Acess token

Tags: oauth, token

I'm working on Magento **OAuth** for integration with a **third party app**.I have a couple of questions:

1. For how much time span an access **token remains valid**?
2. What is the scope of **token based authorization** calls?

(e.g if a call is made based on let's say token 1,meanwhile another token(token 2) is generated, will the first call based on token 1 be still valid? )

Answer (score 0):

**1. For how much time span an access token remains valid?**

---

**1. Token type : Integration**

```
Indefinite. It lasts until it is manually revoked.
```

**2. Token type : Admin**

```
4 hours
```

**3. Token type : Customer**

```
1 hours
```

---

**2. What is the scope of token based authorization calls?(e.g if a call is made based on let's say token 1,meanwhile another token(token 2) is generated, will the first call based on token 1 be still valid? )**

> **No**, `Token 1` will be invalid, after generating the `Token 2`